# No Match Found Exception altough the right match is in the String

Tags: java, regex

I am reading a file in which each line contains the right match and I just want to extract the data. I used the following regex `"\"ms_played\":\\s\"(\\d*)\""` to get `"somedata", "ms_played": "0815", "somedata"`.

I tried multiple regex online test and every test finds a match but my code doesn't.

```
long timeplayed = 0;
Pattern endTimePattern = Pattern.compile("\"ms_played\":\\s\"(\\d*)\"");
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("EndSong_.json"))) {
      String line = null;
      br.readLine();
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String endtime = endTimePattern.matcher(line).group(1);
            timeplayed += Long.parseLong(endtime);
      }
}
```

My expected result was to extract the matcher group 1 which contains an int value.
I am relatively new to Java end regex and would be very grateful if anybody could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex does find the digits in the first capturing group. But you have have to run [find()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--) on the Matcher. Then you can get the first capturing group from it.

For example:

```
long timeplayed = 0;
Pattern endTimePattern = Pattern.compile("\"ms_played\":\\s\"(\\d*)\"");
String line = "\"somedata\", \"ms_played\": \"0815\", \"somedata\"";
Matcher matcher = endTimePattern.matcher(line);
matcher.find();
timeplayed += Long.parseLong(matcher.group(1));
System.out.println(timeplayed); // 815
```

[Exampe in Java](https://ideone.com/Ba1foV) | [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/dxS6Rk/1)